# Concat hebrew chars with underline char

Tags: php, unicode

I am trying to build a function that converts a string to an underlined one.
It works on english string but not on hebrew string.

This is the function:

```
function underline($str){
    $tmp_word = '';
    foreach(str_split($str) as $char){
        $tmp_word.= $char.'&#x0332;';
    }
    return $tmp_word; 
}
```

And some cases:

```
echo underline('abcd') . "<br>";
$hebrew_word = 'אבגד';
echo underline($hebrew_word) . "<br>";
echo underline( hebrev(iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-8", $hebrew_word))). "<br>";
echo underline(iconv("ISO-8859-8", "UTF-8", hebrev(iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-8", $hebrew_word)))). "<br>";
```

The output is:

```
a̲b̲c̲d̲
�̲�̲�̲�̲�̲�̲�̲�̲
�̲�̲�̲�̲
�̲�̲�̲�̲�̲�̲�̲�̲
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: I would suggest using UTF-8 encoding first, as it solves most of encoding problems. Check the functions starting with **mb_**. And check out function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: php string functions aren't unicode-aware. str_split is going to trash your hebrew chars. that's why there's `mb_*()` functions, which ARE multi-byte aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Hebrew, and everything to do with `str_split` not being multibyte-safe.

Try using this function:

```
function mb_str_split( $string ) { 
    return preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $string); 
}
```

This will return an array of characters, as opposed to an array of bytes. The rest of your code should work fine on this.